# Add an array to a property in cosmos graphdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to add an array as one of the property to a vertex but couldn't do it can I have some sample where I can do the same,
I have tried like g.addV('somelabel'). property('arraytoadd',[23,'string'])
But it tells me ) missing query syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only primitive values are allowed as a property.

A property can be multi-valued though. For that the syntax is g.addv().property(‘name’, ‘x’).property(‘name’, ‘y’)